# Reducing Flash FPS from 24 to 12 Without Pacing Lose

Tags: flash, web, actionscript-2, flash-cs6

I haven't used Flash is years. Is there anyway to change a 24fps animation to a 12fps while still retaining the speed? This broadcaster has a crazy spec of 40kb claiming their system can't handle anything more (which seems like crap) but I have to comply.

So far I've removed every single graphic element and also converted all of my motion tweens to classic frame by frame. There's seems to not be too much more I can do.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If host supports version 11.1+, then is possible to compress vectors using LZMA (much smaller swf size).

At publish settings choose JPEG quality to be 70 - 99% (70% usually seems fine) and you can specify each library item (if its picture) render specifics under it's properties. Compression there must not be losless. Deblocking smoothes out if compression quality is low.

In publish settings check "generate size report" to follow it frame by frame, and see where is impact.

As well if you use script working with fonts - embed only characters used, not whole font. (characters used will show up in size report too)

I believe better to use motion tween instead of frame by frame animation (for swf size performance - see the generated size report) Otherwise you do not use swf purpose in creating animations - you just get gif principle there, when each frame contains new image.

Try using vectors were possible, png format.. (sometimes picture is wining over vector if vector shape is complex)

Vectors simplify via Illustrator and images export to web via Photoshop.

40 kbs per distributable 280x280 swf file is achievable!

**If you step from 24 fps to 12 you only win on computing resources per frame, not size of swf.**

*there is all to it, at the top of my head. Anything more to add? swf size is important topic.*